# Javascript get only objects contained in a certain array

Tags: javascript

I have an array

```
const dataitems =  [
    {name:'test1', id:1},
    {name:'test2', id:2},
    {name:'test3', id:3}
  ]

const compares = [1,3]
```

So i want only to get the values of dataitems which id's are contained in compares array values

so at the end i expect to have a final array as

```
const ffinaldataitems =  [
    {name:'test1', id:1},
    {name:'test3', id:3}
  ]
```

which excludes the id 2

So i have tried the following but am stuck

```
  let finaldataitems = []
  dataitems.forEach(item=>{
         if(item.id ) //stuck on how to check and push to the array
  })
```

How do i proceed

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

And [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

> The `includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate.

```js
const dataitems =  [
  {name:'test1', id:1},
  {name:'test2', id:2},
  {name:'test3', id:3}
];

const compares = [1,3];

let finaldataitems = dataitems.filter(item => compares.includes(item.id));

console.log(finaldataitems);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `compares` to `Set` and then use `filter()` on `dataitems` and check is set contains the `id` of object using `Set.prototype.has`

**Note:** for simplicity you can do that without `Set` using `includes()` but it will change the Time-Complexity of algorithm from `O(n)` to `O(n ^ 2)`

```js
const dataitems =  [
    {name:'test1', id:1},
    {name:'test2', id:2},
    {name:'test3', id:3}
  ]

const compares = [1,3];
let set = new Set(compares);
const res = dataitems.filter(x => set.has(x.id));
console.log(res)
```

Another way of doing that is making an object whose keys will `id` of items. And then use `map()` on `compares` to return the item from the previously made object.

```js
const dataitems =  [
    {name:'test1', id:1},
    {name:'test2', id:2},
    {name:'test3', id:3}
  ]

const compares = [1,3];
let obj = dataitems.reduce((ac,a) => (ac[a.id] = a, ac), {});
let res = compares.map(x => obj[x]);
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

While you're in the loop you could check if `item.id` exists in the `compares` array using `indexOf`:

```js
const dataitems = [{
    name: 'test1',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'test2',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'test3',
    id: 3
  }
];

const compares = [1, 3];
let finaldataitems = []
dataitems.forEach(item => {
  if (compares.indexOf(item.id) > -1)
    finaldataitems.push(item);
});

console.log(finaldataitems);
```